# how to stop selecting reapeted option for two label using jsp or php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jsp

```
<label for="FROM">FROM:</label>
<select name="FROM">
  <option selected="" value="Default">(Please select a country)</option>
  <option value="CH">CHENNAI</option>
  <option value="KP">KANCHIPURAM</option>
  <option value="VE">VELLORE</option>
  <option value="BA">BANGALORE</option>
</select>
<BR></BR>

<label for="TO">TO:</label>
<select name="TO">
  <option selected="" value="Default">(Please select a country)</option>
  <option value="CH">CHENNAI</option>
  <option value="KP">KANCHIPURAM</option>
  <option value="VE">VELLORE</option>
  <option value="BA">BANGALORE</option>
</select><br></form>
</br>
```

i'm doing online bus booking project, i set two label  for destination purpose ,' "from" area and "To" area ' using option tag, now i should not same area  ,i  need jsp or php queries

Comment: Where is the error? have you got any error or you just need someone who makes your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add IDs to the two selects, so we can identify and find them. Then add an event-listener to your first select, where changes made to it, will hide the selected value and hide all others.

This uses the *value* of the options, not its text.

```js
$("#from-location").on("change", function() {
  $("#to-location").find("option").show();
  $("#to-location").find("option[value="+this.value+"]").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="FROM">FROM:</label>
<select name="FROM" id="from-location">
  <option selected="" value="Default">(Please select a country)</option>
  <option value="CH">CHENNAI</option>
  <option value="KP">KANCHIPURAM</option>
  <option value="VE">VELLORE</option>
  <option value="BA">BANGALORE</option>
</select>
<BR></BR>

<label for="TO">TO:</label>
<select name="TO" id="to-location">
  <option selected="" value="Default">(Please select a country)</option>
  <option value="CH">CHENNAI</option>
  <option value="KP">KANCHIPURAM</option>
  <option value="VE">VELLORE</option>
  <option value="BA">BANGALORE</option>
</select><br></form>
</br>
```

You might want to add some server-side verification to this after submitting the form as well, where you check that

```
if ($_POST['FROM'] === $_POST['TO']) { 
    /* Error handling */ 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this from within PHP.  This is a simple example; you should adapt it for your own application.  It's not suitable for production use.

```
<?php
if (empty($_REQUEST['FROM'])) {
    exit("Please enter an origin.");
}

if (empty($_REQUEST['TO'])) {
    exit("Please enter a destination.");
}

if ($_REQUEST['FROM'] == $_REQUEST['TO']) {
    exit("Please enter a destination that is different from your origin.");
}
?>
```